# Cypress coverage report for component testing?

Tags: cypress, vite, test-reporting, cypress-component-testing

Currently, the stack that I am using is React JS with Vite. I have written unit tests using Cypress and these tests work perfectly. The problem I am currently facing is generating a coverage report for the component tested.

I need a coverage.xml file that provides me with insights into the code covered by test cases and the code not covered.

I have also tried using IstanbulJs and NYC packages but the coverage which contains the ioc file is not created. Any reference links or clarification will be helpful.